# How to bind variables data into GridView in windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms

Hello all I have some variable in my program in for loop and the values for variables will come dynamically in the for loop. I want to bind those values to grid view. I know how to bind the SQL server data to grid. But how to handle here. How to arrange the column values. Can any one help me please.

I have these variables

```
string changedFile  
int parentIssue 
List<String> Authors
```

I want to add these 3 fields into grid view in for loop. Is there any way to write out side of the for loop?

Comment: Not enough info Have you define any columns, do you have a any specific set of rows ?

Answer (score 1):

Just assign the list as a datasource.

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = Rows;
```

You can arrange columns in the select statement.

```
private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxColumn Authors;
this.Authors.HeaderText = "Authors";
this.Authors.Name = "Authors";
this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add(this.Authors);
this.Authors.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
            "Ayn Rand",
            "Tagore"});
```

Comment: I want to add changedFile and parentIssue also to gird.

Comment: How are you getting the data? StoredProcedure? Show it and I could help better.

Comment: Not stored procedure brother. Those are just a variables.

Comment: I don't see why use a DataGridView for just one line of data. But, you could make a class and bind to an object array object {ChangedFile='', ParentIssue = ''}. Authours could be a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn, that you bind to a list of authors.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
public class BindingObject
{
    public int intMember;
    public string stringMember;
    public string nullMember;
    public BindingObject(int i, string str1, string str2)
    {
        intMember = i;
        stringMember = str1;
        nullMember = str2;
    }
} 

////Somewhere
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
list.Add(new BindingObject(1, "One", null));
list.Add(new BindingObject(2, "Two", null));
list.Add(new BindingObject(3, "Three", null));
dataGrid1.DataSource = list;
```

Comment: This is a more general example, so you can add your list

Answer (score 0):

if you have to set in the loop itself you have to define a template for a gridview in aspx

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridViewField" ClientIDMode="Static"   runat="Server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
               onrowdatabound="gridViewField_RowDataBound"  HorizontalAlign="Center"  AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#ddecfe" >
               <Columns>                   
                   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Field Name">
                       <ItemTemplate>
                           <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblFieldName"></asp:Label>
                       </ItemTemplate>
                   </asp:TemplateField>
</columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

In the for loop you can get each row in codebehind cs file as follows

```
var lblFieldName= gridViewField.Rows[i].FindControl("lblFieldName") as Label
lblFieldName.Text=your loop data
```

i is your loop variable

Comment: The question is actually about WinForms, not ASP.NET WebForms.

Comment: Can you please give me solution about windows forms

Comment: Soryr..i I missed that.I would suggest the to creat a class with members as changesdFile,ParentIssue and author list .When you for loop create an objetc of the class and add to list.You can then bind the datagridview to this list and override the rowbound event to manipulate the data to be displayed